# Is it possible to build a webpage in Fireworks

Tags: web-design, adobe-fireworks

I've been building a simple webpage in Fireworks that is very similar to one that we have on our website currently.

I just want to make sure that before I go to far I will actually be able to upload this page online through an FTP client. I'm worried because it saves it as a .png file and I don't have a ton of experience with web design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Fireworks](http://www.adobe.com/products/fireworks/) is primarily an image editor:

> Adobe® Fireworks® CS5 software enables you to create expressive, highly optimized graphics for the web or virtually any device — from smartphones to kiosks to embedded displays

You can create prototype web sites but need to use something else to produce the actual HTML.

From the same page:

> Prototype in Fireworks and then export standards-compliant CSS layouts with external style sheets for completion in Dreamweaver.

You don't have to use Dreamweaver, but given that you're using Fireworks it might be easier if you do.

Comment: I have dreamweaver b/c I think you are right that this is what I need to do. Thanks. Just need to figure out how to properly export it now.

Answer (score 1):

Website pages can be built with Adobe Fireworks CS4. Pages can be built in three steps—

1. Design the base layout
2. Creating webpages using Fireworks CS4
3. Creating Slices, Linking Pages and Exporting the Layout as a PDF File with Links using Fireworks CS4